# How to debug JavaScript in Firefox via Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have scripts in my ASPX page, in the header section.
I want to debug it (with breakpoints) in Firefox.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. Use Firebug instead, it supports break points. http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: you could use firefox' extention FireBug. It allows you to set break points plus many other features.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398/how-do-i-debug-javascript-in-visual-studio-2005

Comment: @David: actually you can debug JavaScript with Visual Studio; check out the links I posted in my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](https://getfirebug.com/perch/resources/1261603325js.gif))</sub>

---

But if you really wanna use Visual Studio to debug your javascript, here are a couple of pages that will help you out :

1. [VS 2008 JavaScript Debugging](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/vs-2008-javascript-debugging) (ScottGu)
2. [VISUAL STUDIO 2008 JAVASCRIPT DEBUGGING](https://www.geekzone.co.nz/vs2008/4733)
3. [How to debug JavaScript with Visual Web Developer Express](https://web.archive.org/web/20100922172437/http://www.berniecode.com:80/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/)
4. [Visual Studio 2008 simplifies JavaScript debugging](https://web.archive.org/web/20080517152548/http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/programming-and-development/?p=672)
5. [JavaScript Debugging in Visual Studio 2008](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet) (Video)

Comment: check if this article helps you out : http://www.sweetvision.com/2008/02/26/quick-tip-firebug-break-points-not-breaking/

Comment: or this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651404/firebug-breakpoint-doesnt-hit